# How does monitor size influence a desktop application

Tags: compatibility, resolution, desktop

I want to know if a fixed sized application would look exactly the same(talking about the size of the window) on any monitor. Let me give you an example.
Let's say that I have a PyQt5 application with a fixed size of 600x400 pixels. I run this application on my **14 inch LENOVO** laptop(its resolution is the recommended one, 16:9) and it will look fine, application's window is not too big for the monitor and also not too small. But if I take this application and run it on a PC which has an **22 inch ACER** monitor(same resolution, 16:9) will the application's window stretch or will it look smaller? I mean, the a 600x400 window would look smaller on a big monitor right? Or will the OS somehow stretch it?

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?

Comment: I added more details. Hope it's enough. If not please tell me what kind of details do you need

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to programming?

Comment: It's about application development, not exactly coding. I want to know how will an application behave on a different device with a different monitor size.

Comment: ...why not simply try it out and see what happens? What have you tried to resolve the problem?